# ¿Se puede hacer una búsqueda selectiva de preguntas "closed" o "on hold"?

Tags: soporte, búsqueda

Estaba buscando una pregunta cuyo contenido no recuerdo pero que estoy casi seguro que fue cerrada. Tras pasar varias páginas sin éxito, se me ocurrió intentar por la palabra clave "close", pero no parece proporcionar los resultados que busco (preguntas cerradas).

¿Se puede hacer una búsqueda de ese tipo, para localizar (a ser posible solo) preguntas cerradas  y/o "on hold"? ¿Es eso posible para los usuarios normales o se requieren superpoderes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Estabas cerca! Debes usar:

- [`closed:1`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1) (o `closed:yes`, o `closed:true`)

Tienes toda la información al respecto en el artículo de ayuda [How do I search?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/searching). `closed` pertenece a una serie de operadores booleanos como `wiki`, `hasnotice`, `hasaccepted`, etc. que puedes definir con `yes`/`1`/`true` o `no`/`0`/`false`.

Respecto los privilegios necesarios para utilizar estos operadores: no, están disponibles para todo el mundo independientemente de su reputación. Lo único que cambia con la reputación es la posibilidad de usar [`deleted:1`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1), que a partir de cierto punto ([Access To Moderator Tools](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), reputación 2000 en sitios Beta) está disponible para que los usuarios puedan buscar sus propias publicaciones eliminadas.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias